solving system of differential equations with odient
I tried to solve system of two  differential equations using scipy.integrate.odient.
The results are far from my  expectations as one can see from the plots I attached below.
This is the system of ODEs:

where alpha and beth functions are functions of the time t, and repsernting function of the input signal.
My plots for the signals in my code are:

The expected plots

My code:
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint ,solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def normalize_array(A):
    # Convert to NumPy array if it's not already
    A = np.array(A)
    
    # Calculate min and max
    min_val = np.min(A)
    max_val = np.max(A)
    
    # Normalize
    if max_val == min_val:
        # Avoid division by zero if all values are the same
        return np.zeros_like(A)
    else:
        return (A - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
def solve_system_of_ODE(init_vec,t,alpha_func,beth_func,gamma,delta):

   
    # Define the system of differential equations
    def system(init_vec,t,alpha_func,beth_func,gamma,delta):
        x,A = init_vec
        dydt = [alpha_func(t)*(A-x)-beth_func(t)*x-gamma*x+delta*(1-A),
                delta*(1-A)-gamma*x]
        return dydt
    

    # Solve the system of differential equations
    solution = odeint(system,init_vec,t,args=(alpha_func,beth_func,gamma,delta))
    return solution
    
# Initial conditions
init_vec = [0,0]


# Time points where the solution is evaluated
t = np.linspace(0,50,500)

signals=[lambda t: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-5 * (t - 10))),
         lambda t: 0.3*np.sin(t/3)+ 0.25*np.sin(t/2)+np.sin(t/5)+np.sin(t/10),
         lambda t: np.sin(t/3)]
n_signals=len(signals)

delta=0.2
gamma=0.4

X_lst,A_lst=[],[]
for i in range(len(signals)):
    alpha=signals[i]
    beth=signals[i]
    solution=solve_system_of_ODE(init_vec,t,alpha,beth,gamma,delta)
    
    X = solution[:,0]
    X=normalize_array(X)
    A = solution[:,1]
    A=normalize_array(A)
    
    X_lst.append(X)
    A_lst.append(A)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, n_signals, figsize=(10, 5))

for i in range(len(signals)):
    y=signals[i](t)
    axes[0,i].plot(t,y)
    axes[0, i].set_title(f" signal({i+1})")
    axes[0, i].grid(True)
    axes[0, i].set_xlabel('t')
    axes[0, i].set_ylabel('u(t)')

    #plot the results
    axes[1,i].plot(t, X_lst[i], label='X(t)')
    axes[1,i].plot(t, A_lst[i], label='A(t)')
    axes[1,i].set_title('Solutions ')
    axes[1,i].set_xlabel('t')
    axes[1,i].set_ylabel('Solutions X, A')
    axes[1, i].grid(True)
    axes[1, i].legend()
    


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I tried to change the initial condition of the ODE system - but it is not help me.

The equations in your code do not match the equations in the photo you shared.
